How to avoid 'undefined' error when using viewChild signal with RxJS in Angular?
I'm trying to track click events on an element in my Angular template using the viewChild signal and the fromEvent operator from RxJS:
@Component({
  selector: "app-example",
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <button #myButton>click me</button>
    Last clicked: {{ lastClick() }}
  `,
})
export class ExampleComponent {
  buttonRef = viewChild("myButton", { read: ElementRef });
  buttonEl = computed(() => this.buttonRef()?.nativeElement);
  lastClick = toSignal(
    fromEvent(this.buttonEl(), "click").pipe(map(() => Date.now()))
  );
}


But I'm getting the following error: TypeError: target is undefined.
How can I make sure that the value of this.buttonEl() is not undefined?
I can't use static: true in the viewChild signal's options, like I could with the @ViewChild decorator. I also can't use viewChildFn() outside of an injection context.

Instead of using viewChild at all, you can simply set the signal from the button's click handler.  This simplifies your code because the controller doesn't need to worry about any template concerns, only data concerns.
@Component({
  selector: "app-example",
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <button (click)="setLastClick()"> click me </button>
    Last clicked: {{ lastClick() }}
  `,
})
export class ExampleComponent {
  lastClick = signal(undefined);

  setLastClick() {
    this.lastClick.set(Date.now());
  }
}

StackBlitz example.

You can use toObservable from @angular/core/rxjs-interop to convert the viewChild signal to an Observable and then use the switchMap operator to switch to listening for the click event once you have the element.
import { Component, ElementRef, computed, viewChild } from "@angular/core";
import { toObservable, toSignal } from "@angular/core/rxjs-interop";
import { fromEvent, map, switchMap } from "rxjs";

@Component({
  selector: "app-example",
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <button #myButton>click me</button>
    Last clicked: {{ lastClick() }}
  `,
})
export class ExampleComponent {
  buttonRef = viewChild("myButton", { read: ElementRef });
  buttonEl = computed(() => this.buttonRef()?.nativeElement);

  lastClick = toSignal(
    toObservable(this.buttonEl).pipe(
      switchMap((el) => fromEvent(el, "click").pipe(map(() => Date.now())))
    )
  );
}

